# Visual Studio 2008 deleting my file?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, delete-file

I am using Visual Studio 2008 for a ASP.NET MVC web application project and I use a svn repository (ankhsvn plugin).  Today I checked in my code at 10:30am and continued developing primarily on a single Javascript file.  Late in the day, after trying to save the file Visual Studio prompted me to save the file which was weird since I was not trying to change the name of the file.  I have seen issues like this before in VS, so I copied the line I was trying to save, closed down the IDE and reopened it.  Once I reopened the IDE and solution, the Javascript file was not longer in my working copy folder on my machine.  It totally vanished and VS2008 did not have it in the project file.

Please help, I lost a good amount of code.  Is there any way to restore this file. Why would Visual Studio removed this file and not leave any trace of it.